# abstract a fixture with `pytest`

Tags: python, unit-testing, inheritance, pytest

Suppose I have an abstract class `A` that is inherited by a non abstract classes `B` and some other classes. There is a property that I want to test on all sub-classes of `A`. My idea is to have a test class that has a function that will test the property and provide the instance of `A` as a fixture. Maybe code can explain it better, I would want to implement something like this :

```py
import pytest
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class A(ABC):
  @abstractmethod
  def property():
    raise NotImplementedError

class B(A):
  def property():
    return True

class APropertyTester:
  def test_property(self, tested_class: C):
    assert tested_class.property()

class TestB(APropertyTester):
  @pytest.fixture()
  def tested_class(self):
    return A()
```

---

I have tried adding the flag `@pytest.mark.usefixtures('tested_class')` to `TestA` but this doesn't seem to work. And I don't know what to try here. Maybe someone knows a good practice to do those things.